# How to check if datagridview input type matches with the underlying data type in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I want to check if the datagridview input valuetype matches with the respective cells datatype. For example, if I give numeric input it will check if the respective databound datagridview column's datatype is numeric or not. If string is given as input then it will show error message and vice versa. I have tried like this:

```
private void dgvLoadTable_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.FormattedValue.GetType() != dgvLoadTable.CurrentCell.ValueType.UnderlyingSystemType)
     MessageBox.Show("Input type is wrong"); }
}
```

But this shows error message even when the input is correct. Can anyone tell me how to do it correctly, please?

Comment: `e.FormattedValue` is `object` and it's used to pass user input (text). You can try to parse it to see if type match. I was using fixed columns `DataGridView` (not re-order-able) and `e.ColumnIndex` in simple `switch`. `CurrentCell.ValueType` may do as well with [dynamic parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2380467/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

I have analyze your source code. Everything works fine for me. Maybe there is error in your DataSource?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<Class> DataSource = new BindingList<Class>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        dgvLoadTable.DataSource = DataSource;            
    }

    private void dgvLoadTable_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.FormattedValue.GetType() != dgvLoadTable.CurrentCell.ValueType.UnderlyingSystemType)
            MessageBox.Show("Input type is wrong");
    }
}

public class Class
{
    public string StringData { get; set; }
    public int IntData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the discrepance between Value and FormattedValue or ValueType and FormattedValueType. ValueType is the real type of the column. FormattedValueType is the type which is used by the grid to display the value or the type of the user input. If you have a integer row, the value is formatted to a string. The same: if you input an integer you just input a string which is parsed to integer by the grid. So it is difficult to perform the check you want in this way because all your inputs just are strings and it is difficult to decide if you mean 1 or "1".

Use the DataError event of the DataGrid to react on wrong input. (e.g. letters in a integer column)

Comment: I am using entity model as datasource, so DataError Event willnot work.

Answer (score 0):

`e.FormattedValue.GetType()` will return String for `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`(for example for `DataGridViewImageColumn`, it will return `System.Drawing.Bitmap`), same as `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValueType`, which is readonly. To set type for column, you can do this:

```
myColumn.ValueType = typeof(int);
```

Then, instead of `CellValidating` event, you can subscribe to `DataError` event (it will get raised whenever data entered into the cell by the user or the application is wrong). (When data in the column is bound to datasource, `ValueType` is assigned by default to the type of bound data)

```
 void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // process your data error here
            Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ValueType + "\n" + e.Exception); 
        }
```